# Articulate Storyline custom Menu Tab

Tags: javascript, html, articulate-storyline, articulate

I need help from anybody who has used and knows both Articulate Storyline and HTML / JavaScript coding.

When someone publishes from Articulate Storyline to WEB (HTML5 only) with the option of Menu Tab visible at all times, is it possible that by tweaking the coding I could create another active Tab behind the Menu Tab?

Please look at the image below for clarification.
[image: Other Tab example]

It's useless for me to copy and paste the code here because I don't know from all the files that Articulate publishes which one is the one related to the player or more specifically related to the menu tab on the player.

I will appreciate any guidance as to how to tackle this issue and if this is something that can be done or can't.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it better to create another tab using software "Articulate Storyline" if there's an option? When the whole course is prepared by software, changing some parts by getting into its code is much painful then re-uploading the course.

Comment: I know. Yes, you can create another hidden "tab" that will sit in the player next to the "open" menu tab. And its true that messing around with some parts it's not wise.

But I want a tab that sits next to the open Menu tab. I'm pretty sure that for someone who knows about coding this is not a complicated thing. Why? because the structure that withholds the tabs its already there coded and the task is to "add" another selectable Tab.

Comment: at least personally I have no idea of what you're talking, who may know how does that "code stucture" tabs looks in your machine? Someone who may know programming is not wisdow! You should come up with some code, if you're pretty sure its easy.

Comment: I will provide more information with images and code shortly. What I want is some feedback from someone who knows a bit about articulate and has ventured in to tweaking the code of the published files.

Comment: @developer

Ok, here I got more info and strings of codes.
**I will recap.**
I'm Using Articulate Storyline
I'm exporting as HTML5 only
I will like to tweak or change the frame code in order to create a new tab where the menu tab sits (left side) and in that new tab add images (.PNG)
The below image shows the files and folders that come out after exporting
[http://imgur.com/a/PnBY4]
The below image is what it's inside the story content folder
[http://imgur.com/a/PnBY4]

Comment: 1. Images are deleted or they didn't show up.
2. No need for images, if you want to make changes on some piece of code then post the code and tell what exactly you want change but didn't find any possible way on the internet how to do it. This is what StackOverflow is for